# ffmpeg - mix a video with a sound in code

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to dub a video with sound.

I've managed to re-encode a video using ffmpeg, but how do I save out the audio?

I've looked in api-example.c, at the audio_encode_example and video_encode_example functions, however they output to separate files, I'd like to output to one file.

Thanks,
Ash

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like [this](http://txt.binnyva.com/2008/08/add-audio-to-a-video-file-using-ffmpeg/) ? You can also look at 'Mix a video with a sound file' section [here](http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/19-ffmpeg-commands-for-all-needs).

Comment: Thanks but, unfortunately I need to do it in code rather than with command line parameters. Do you have any pointers for that?

Comment: @Cairo - Did you try with ffmpeg.c file? There are many options to set the decoding parameters in this file e.g. opt_audio_codec, opt_video_codec, opt_audio_rate, opt_video_rate, opt_default etc. Just set the necessary parameters from this [link](http://txt.binnyva.com/2008/08/add-audio-to-a-video-file-using-ffmpeg/) or this [link](http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/19-ffmpeg-commands-for-all-needs) using these functions before calling transcode or av_encode function from main method of ffmpeg.c